# I want to make ban with role bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I wanted to make ban bot with role

but it raised errors

here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def roleban(ctx, role:discord.Role):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in user:
            try:
                await user.ban()
            except:
                pass
        else:
            pass
```

and error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'Member' is not iterable
```

Comment: Use `if role in user.roles` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.roles

Answer (score 0):

you can however get a list of all their roles using .`roles`. see if a user has a given role we can use `user.roles`:

```
@client.command()
async def roleban(ctx, role:discord.Role):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in user.roles:
            try:
                await user.ban()
            except:
                pass
        else:
            pass
```

for more information go to [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member)